# How to rename 'Tag Base' with WPeC 3.8?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, tags

In Wordpress>Settings>Permalinks there is an option at the bottom of the page to change the 'Tag Base'.

I've entered 'testtag' in this option and saved, but my tag pages are still displaying as 'tagged' (eg www.example.com/tagged/tagcategory).

wpsc-functions.php in the wp-ecommerce>wpsc-core folder... on line 319 'tagged' can be renamed which will change the URL's generated by things like the tag cloud, which in part solves the problem - but when you click on and request those new URL's it generates a 404 error.

Does anyone have any ideas please on how I can rename this.

I'm using WP 3.1 and Wordpress E-commerce Plugin 3.8. I've got a test site on www.chainsawdr.com. An example of a tag URL can be found by clicking a link in the tag cloud.

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading

ChainsawDR.com

Comment: do you have a tagging_functions file in wpsc 3.8? I'm sticking with 3.7.8 as ut seems to be far more stable. If there isnt a tagging functions file have a look at the docs on getshopped because there is a list in there about which php file does what that may help with tracking down the file you need to edit

Comment: Hi Screaming Violet,
no I can't see a tagging_functions file in wpsc 3.8, and I didn't have any joy with the documentation on getshopped. So far the closest I have come is changing the wpsc-functions.php file but I'm guessing that once I do this a template file is no longer associated with it. I'll keep looking.
Thanks for your help and for putting me onto this forum, seems to have a lot more info here.
Cheers
Dean

Comment: I'm assuming that it's a permalinks issue, and that I'd need to do a rewrite using .htaccess - but manually doing this is a little advanced for me at the moment, I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags are a custom taxonomy called `product_tag` in WPEC 3.8+, they're not the same taxonomy as default WordPress tags so that's why tagbase has no effect.

Line 315 in wpsc-core/wpsc-functions.php:

```
register_taxonomy( 'product_tag', 'wpsc-product', array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => '/' . sanitize_title_with_dashes( _x( 'tagged', 'slug, part of url', 'wpsc' ) ),
        'with_front' => false )
) );
```

*Edit- I somehow skipped over the part of your question where you point out the above, however, changing the slug in this file and then flushing your rewrite rules WILL change the slug, but you're editing core files which is always bad.

The question I suppose should then be "Is it possible to override something set elsewhere in a `register_taxonomy` call?"

Comment: When I'm a little better at coding I'll most likely revisit that question, but for now it's working thanks to your help (I thought I had flushed my theme's cache but mustn't have done).

Works like a dream now, thanks for your help!